# How to SLAM Mapping with Ultrasonic Sensors instead of Kinect?

Tags: slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am trying to do the SLAM mapping with an ultrasonic sensor(HC-SR04). It works on my raspberry pi using Python.

I wonder if there is any package I can use to use **RViz** and **gmapping**, with my ultrasonic sensor. I do not know how to publish the distance reading information from Raspberry Pi to my turtlebot laptop.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210682/how-to-slam-mapping-with-ultrasonic-sensors-instead-of-kinect?/) by [hw2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/22678/hw2016/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-06-05

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Doing SLAM with just a 1-point range sensor is impossible but you can still do some cheapo mapping, please take a look at the Python code that I wrote at this repo: https://github.com/RiccardoGiubilato/ros_autonomous_car. Here I have a crius board hooked up to a wheel encoder and an ultrasonic sensor. The crius (based on atmega328) publishes odometry and range data which is used by a Udoo board mounted on the car itself to build an OccupancyGrid.

---

Originally posted by [RiccardoGiubilato](https://answers.ros.org/users/32342/riccardogiubilato/) with karma: 76 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0